# Getting error failed to load registered .net framework data provider while trying to import data from import wizard in sql server

Tags: sql-server

I am trying import data from a `csv` file into a table by using import data task in `sql server`.
Here are the steps:

1. right click on database
2. go to tasks
3. go to import data

then it shows error in dialogue box that :

> failed to load registered .net framework data provider.

Please help.

Comment: it seems you might  have done something in your machine config:https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/spike/2008/07/18/failed-to-find-or-load-the-registered-net-framework-data-provider/

Comment: I never opened machine.config file.